# ModelState is always valid in ASP.NET.CORE 2.2 Web Api

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have an Asp.Net Core 2.2 web api project.Recently i tried to add validation on the models by adding DataAnnotation or the FluentValidation library.

In my Unit tests though i can see that even passing invalid model values the model state is valid.

StartUp.cs

```
services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2)
        .AddFluentValidation();

services.AddTransient<IValidator<ClientDto>, ClientValidator>();
```

ClientController

My Controller inherits from the ControllerBase and has the [ApiController] attribute.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Create([FromBody] ClientDto client)
    {

        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            return BadRequest();

        await _clientsService.Create(client);

        var clientAdded = await _clientsService.GetCustomer(c => c.IntegralFileName == client.IntegralFileName);

        return CreatedAtAction("Create", client, clientAdded);

    }
```

ClientDto.cs

```
 public class ClientDto
{
    public string Id { get; set; }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public bool Admin { get; set; }

    public bool Active { get; set; }
}
```

ClienValidator.cs

```
public class ClientValidator : AbstractValidator<ClientDto>
{
    public ClientValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(x => x.Id).NotNull();
        RuleFor(x => x.FirstName).Length(4, 20);
        RuleFor(x => x.LastName).Length(3, 20);
    }
}
```

I think i tried everything , some of them:

1)Removed Fluent Validation and replace it with DataAnnotations

2)Replace AddMcv with

```
   services.AddMvcCore()
            .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2)
            .AddJsonFormatters()
            .AddApiExplorer()
            .AddAuthorization()
            .AddDataAnnotations()
            .AddFluentValidation(fv => fv.RegisterValidatorsFromAssemblyContaining<ClientValidator>());
```

But i cant see any difference in the ModelState value.
Any Ideas??

Thanks

Comment: It would be helpful to see your actual test. You've called it a unit test, and if that is in fact the case, then validation will *never* work, as that's only going to happen as part of the modelbinding process, which doesn't run without the rest of the ASP.NET Core machinery. To test this, you'll need to do integration testing using the test server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Model state validation is not happening (or it's right to say that model binding does not happening) during unit-testing. [This article](https://alenjalex.github.io/dev/dev/Asp.Net-Core-ModelState-Validation-Using-UnitTest/) describes some ways to implement what you want

Comment: First of all the article is great and appreciate it.However model state is valid even in normal debugging , maybe found out in a weird way the issue , but then i checked with postman and still model state is always valid.

Comment: Well, that's odd. Tried to reproduce your issue based on the code in your question - validation works as expected. `client` param in Create method has all passed values? Can you show this postman's request body

Comment: One more time in my career , the issue is resolved without knowing why.Cleaning , rebuilding updating the nuget packages , made the validation to work properly,

Answer (score 0):

Try adding attribute to your Dto:

```
[Validator(typeof(ClientValidator))]
public class ClientDto
```

Comment: Try [FluentValidation.Attributes.Validator(typeof(ClientValidator))]

Comment: https://fluentvalidation.net/upgrading-to-8.html.In the new version this attribute is removed